# Eliminate blank strings using SplitString

Tags: string, delphi, parsing, delphi-xe, pascal

Is there a way to exclude blank strings from the dynamic array resulting of the SplitString function (Delphi XE, StrUtils), without having to iterate through the array?

If not, can anyone suggest the most efficient way to do it? Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
function SplitStringNoEmpty(myString : string; myDelimiters : string):TStringDynArray;
var
    words_array_pre : TStringDynArray;
    words_array_pos : TStringDynArray;
    array_length : Integer;
    actual_length : Integer;
    current_word : string;

    procedure AddElement(const Str: string);
    begin
      words_array_pos[actual_length]:= Str;
      inc(actual_length);
    end;
begin
    words_array_pre:= SplitString(myString, whitespaceNewLineCharacterSet + punctuationCharacterSet);
    array_length:= Length(words_array_pre);
    if (array_length >0) then
    begin
      actual_length:= 0;
      SetLength(words_array_pos, array_length);
      for current_word in words_array_pre do
      begin
        if (current_word <> '') then
          AddElement(current_word);
      end;
      SetLength(words_array_pos, actual_length);
      result:= words_array_pos;
    end
    else
      result:= words_array_pre;
end;
```

Comment: Have you considered just doing whatever SplitString does, but without including empty elements in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to remove certain elements of an array without iterating over the array — how else would you know which elements to remove? The improvements to make to your code are to remove the need to allocate an *extra* array. You can cull the original array in-place:

```
function SplitStringNoEmpty(const s, delimiters: string): TStringDynArray;
var
  Src, Dest: Integer;
begin
  Result := SplitString(s, delimiters);
  if Length(Result) <> 0 then begin
    // Push all non-empty values to front of array
    Dest := 0;
    for Src := 0 to High(Result) do
      if Result[Src] <> '' then begin
        if Src <> Dest then
          Result[Dest] := Result[Src];
        Inc(Dest);
      end;
    // Remove excess from end of array
    SetLength(Result, Dest);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization Rob! StrUtils should be added a similar function.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own implementation of the SplitString function ignoring the empty strings.

Check this sample

```
function SplitString2(const S, Delimiters: string): TStringDynArray;
var
  LIndex, SIndex, FIndex, LMax, LPos: Integer;
  foo : string;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if S <> '' then
  begin
    LPos   := 0;
    LMax   := 0;
    SIndex := 1;

    for LIndex := 1 to Length(S) do
      if IsDelimiter(Delimiters, S, LIndex) then Inc(LMax);

    SetLength(Result, LMax + 1);

    repeat
      FIndex := FindDelimiter(Delimiters, S, SIndex);
      if FIndex <> 0 then
      begin
        foo:= Copy(S, SIndex, FIndex - SIndex);
        if foo<>'' then
        begin
          Result[LPos] := foo;
          Inc(LPos);
        end;
        SIndex := FIndex + 1;
      end;
    until (LPos = LMax) or (FIndex=0);

    if LPos<LMax then
     SetLength(Result, LPos + 1);

    foo:=Copy(S, SIndex, Length(S) - SIndex + 1);
    if foo<>'' then
     Result[LMax] := foo
    else
     SetLength(Result, LPos);
  end;
end;
```